# How to detect if a user closes the browser or tab before finishing a booking process, using PHP and MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, session, cookies

I am building an event booking system, once the user select a table, I am updating the MySQL table with the table-status="booking" once the payment and all the functionalities are completed I am again updating it table-status="booked".

Now the problem is, in checkout when the user realize the price of the table they simply close the tab or browser and leave and my table-status remains in table-status="booking". I need to catch this and need to update my table-status to table-status="not"

I do have the session variable for the user but when they close the browser.

Comment: Not change value directly to table , hold value in session upto checkout, once user going make payment  then you can update your database

Comment: Thank u.. though what will happen if other user also see the same table and picked?

Comment: create a extra filed in database, when user add table in cart update this extrafields with current date time , and run a function in every 30 min and check is there any  table-status="booking". and added time in more then 30 min if you found this then simple make table-status="not"

Comment: I feel like this has been tackled before. Why re-invent the wheel?

Answer (score 0):

you need to do php cron job. If u want do check every for example 30 mins. soo server will automaticly execut your script every 30mins and will for example delete or change status of users who didnt finished payment. You can google about cron job on google.